# MySQL join between table with 1 row extremely slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I was testing some join queries on a subset of my data. I was joining 5 tables as specified below. Initially I had only 1 row in the `B` table and over 55 million rows in the `A` table, tables C,D,E had less than 1000 rows. 
The join query instantaneously joined tables A,C,D,E but when I added B to the join it took forever. When I added another row to table B (2 rows now),
it was able to join instantaneously. All tables have relevant indexes on columns that are joined. I have never seen this behaviour before, any explanation?

```
MariaDB [test]> desc A;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| BID          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| CID          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| DID          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| EID          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

MariaDB [test]> desc B;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(250)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

MariaDB [test]> desc C;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(250)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

MariaDB [test]> desc D;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(250)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

MariaDB [test]> desc E;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(250)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

here are the explain plans for both cases:

```
######### with 1 rows in B 
MariaDB [test]> EXPLAIN EXTENDED select *  from  A use index (PRIMARY), B, C, D,  samples as E where A.BID = B.uid and A.CID=C.uid and A.DID = D.uid and A.EID = E.uid and A.uid>0 order by A.uid limit 10;
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+-----------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys  | key     | key_len | ref             | rows     | filtered | Extra                                           |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+-----------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | B     | index  | PRIMARY,ix_uid | name    | 752     | NULL            |        1 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort    |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | A     | range  | PRIMARY        | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL            | 27965017 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | E     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ix_uid | PRIMARY | 4       | hg38.A.EID      |        1 |   100.00 |                                                 |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | C     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ix_uid | PRIMARY | 4       | hg38.A.CID      |        1 |   100.00 |                                                 |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | D     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ix_uid | PRIMARY | 4       | hg38.A.DID      |        1 |   100.00 |                                                 |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+-----------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

 MariaDB [test]> EXPLAIN EXTENDED select *  from  A use index (PRIMARY), C, D, E where A.CID=C.uid and A.DID = D.uid and A.EID = E.uid and A.uid>0 order by A.uid limit 10;
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+-----------------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys  | key     | key_len | ref             | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+-----------------+----------+----------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | A     | range  | PRIMARY        | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL            | 27965017 |   100.00 | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | E     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ix_uid | PRIMARY | 4       | hg38.A.EID      |        1 |   100.00 |             |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | C     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ix_uid | PRIMARY | 4       | hg38.A.CID      |        1 |   100.00 |             |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | D     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ix_uid | PRIMARY | 4       | hg38.A.DID      |        1 |   100.00 |             |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+-----------------+----------+----------+-------------+
4 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

######### with 2 rows in B
 MariaDB [test]> EXPLAIN EXTENDED select *  from  A use index (PRIMARY), B, C, D,  samples as E where A.BID = B.uid and A.CID=C.uid and A.DID = D.uid and A.EID = E.uid and A.uid>0 order by A.uid limit 10;
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+---------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys  | key     | key_len | ref                 | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+---------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | A     | range  | PRIMARY        | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL                | 27965017 |   100.00 | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | D     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ix_uid | PRIMARY | 4       | hg38.A.DID          |        1 |   100.00 |             |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | E     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ix_uid | PRIMARY | 4       | hg38.A.EID          |        1 |   100.00 |             |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | C     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ix_uid | PRIMARY | 4       | hg38.A.CID          |        1 |   100.00 |             |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | B     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ix_uid | PRIMARY | 4       | hg38.A.BID          |        1 |   100.00 |             |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+---------------------+----------+----------+-------------+

 MariaDB [test]> EXPLAIN EXTENDED select *  from  A use index (PRIMARY), C, D, E where A.CID=C.uid and A.DID = D.uid and A.EID = E.uid and A.uid>0 order by A.uid limit 10;
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+-----------------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys  | key     | key_len | ref             | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+-----------------+----------+----------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | A     | range  | PRIMARY        | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL            | 27965017 |   100.00 | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | E     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ix_uid | PRIMARY | 4       | hg38.A.EID      |        1 |   100.00 |             |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | C     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ix_uid | PRIMARY | 4       | hg38.A.CID      |        1 |   100.00 |             |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | D     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ix_uid | PRIMARY | 4       | hg38.A.DID      |        1 |   100.00 |             |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+-----------------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Post explain plans for each case.

Comment: If you delete the second row is it slow again?

Comment: removing the second row slows it down again.